# Are 3rd party plugins customizable in Custom Wordpress Themes

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am creating a wordpress theme with the help of bootstrap, however I would like to use a 3rd party carousel plugin and customise it according to my need. Is it possible? If yes, then how?

P.S. I am new to Wordpress, and I just started learning php.

Comment: Q: Can I use a 3rd party carousel plugin (in conjunction with Bootstrap) in the Wordpress theme I'm creating?  A: In all likelihood.  In general, there shouldn't be any reason why not.  The *FIRST* thing you need to do, of course, is to learn enough PHP .. and HTML and CSS - and, it sounds like, Javascript as well - to create your own "hello world" WP theme.

Comment: You can Use Bootstrap Carousel Plugin Try this https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp  its easy to customized